# Sublime coffeescript comment formatting?

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext

Does anyone know how to (or if it is possible) to format coffeescript comments in Sublime?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by formatting comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the plugin [CoffeeScript.tmbundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) to provide CoffeeScript syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2.

You can install this plugin to Sublime Text 2 by:

**In Linux:**

1. `cd ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`
2. `git clone git://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle.git`

(On Windows, its `git clone C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages`)

**Result Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: The normal paragraph formatting functions appear to handle comments: Edit -> Wrap is clever enough to keep any comments intact and not wrap the program code in as well.